# How to run a script on logging out?

Tags: linux, unix

In an attempt to execute a script when a user logs out from a shell session, I added

```
trap SCRIPT 0 1 2 15;
```

in `.profile.`.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 3):

The different shells run different files on logout - you can execute your script from one of these files, depending on you shell:

- for **bash** the file is *~/.bash_logout*
- for **tcsh** the file is *~/.logout*
- for **zsh** the file is *~/.zlogout*

Comment: I'm doing this exercise http://i.imgur.com/Jg6VW.png and i have to use .profile and trap

Comment: its from The Unix programming Environment By Robert Pike and Brain W. Kernighan

Comment: @Furqan So what? We are not here to answer exercises. Vladimir's answer is correct and works.